# How to create a new column with values after groupby & rollingsum?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multiple-columns, rolling-sum

I am trying to create a new column in an existing `df`. The values of the new column are created by a combination of the groupby and rolling sum. How do I do this?

I've tried two approaches both resulting in either NaN values or 'incompatible index of the inserted column with frame index'

df = something like this:

```
    HomeTeam    FTHP
0   Bristol Rvs 0
1   Crewe           0
2   Hartlepool  3
3   Huddersfield    1
```

and I've tried:

(1)

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('HomeTeam')['FTHP'].rolling(4).sum()
```

(2)

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('HomeTeam').FTHP.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(4).mean())
```

(1) outputs the following which are the values that I would like to add in a new column.

```
HomeTeam        
Brighton     12      NaN
             36      NaN
             49      NaN
             72      2.0
             99      2.0
```

And I am trying to add these values in a new columns next to the appropriate HomeTeam. Resulting in a NaN for the first three (as it is rolling(4)) and pick up values after, something like:

```
    HomeTeam    FTHP      RollingMean
0   Bristol Rvs 0         NaN
1   Crewe           0         NaN
2   Hartlepool  3         NaN
3   Huddersfield    1         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure alignment on the original (non-duplicated) index:

```
df.groupby('HomeTeam', as_index=False)['FTHP'].rolling(4).sum().reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

---

With a `df`:

```
  HomeTeam  FTHP
A        a     0
B        b     1
C        b     2
D        a     3
E        b     4
```

grouping with `as_index=False` adds an [`ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) value as the 0th level, preserving the original index in the 1st level:

```
df.groupby('HomeTeam', as_index=False)['FTHP'].rolling(2).sum()
#0  A    NaN
#   D    3.0
#1  B    NaN
#   C    3.0
#   E    6.0
#Name: FTHP, dtype: float64
```

Drop level=0 to ensure alignment on the original index. Your original index should not be duplicated, else you get a `ValueError`.